# What is the meaning of flung in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> The doors to the world have been flung wide open, and the view that’s available is staggering.

Upon checking flung - throw, cast or move quickly does not fit with this sentence.
staggering deeply shocking!
it is from the book “the one thing”

Comment: Why does `cast, move quickly` not fit??

Comment: does not seem natural to me, do the author means that the world moves so fast that a lot of opportunities exists?

Answer (score 2):

To fling or throw something open is to open it suddenly and completely.

[Fling something open](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/fling-something-open)

Answer (score 0):

The important point is that it is referring to the ***doors*** when it says ***flung wide open***.

This is *metaphorical*. They are using "doors to the world" as a metaphor (and what for I couldn't tell you without more context - there's a few possibilities), and saying they have been opened suddenly and completely, possibly forcefully. Now they're open, it say, the view through them is staggering - and that's still metaphor.